# Use EF Core 5 many-to-many relation with the "Join table" that has extra data

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I would like to ask if anyone can help me with EF Core 5.
I have two tables that are in "many-to-many" relationship: on the Join table, in addition to the columns that act as foreign keys I also have other columns that I would like to map in EF Core.
The only solution I can think of is to create the relationship as it was done in EF Core 3, that is to use a "one to many" relationship with the join table.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Ps. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Just handle it as two 1-to-many relations with the join table on the n-side. Of course then this join-entity must be represented by a class in your code. See this [image](https://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/2011/12/06/how-to-use-sqlbulkinsert-for-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-a-entity-framework-4-2-model-with-c-4-0/) as an example

Comment: *"The only solution I can think ..."* And what's wrong with that? It is a standard relational design for such data, regardless of EF 6, Core 3, 5 whatever. The EFC 5 skip navigations are just a shortcut for M2M **without** additional fields in the linking table, which is not the case here. Also even for such simple type of M2M relationship no one is *forced* to use the skip navigation approach. Because both implicit and explicit join entity designs have their pros and cons.

Answer (score 7):

> The only solution I can think of is to create the relationship as it was done in EF Core 3, that is to use a "one to many" relationship with the join table.

You can have your cake and eat it too.

EF Core 5 supports custom linking entities and using skip-level navigation at the same time.

There is an example in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#other-relationship-patterns) where the linking entity is in the model, has additional properties, but the main entities skip over the linking entity with Collection Navigation Properties.

```
internal class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Tags)
            .WithMany(p => p.Posts)
            .UsingEntity<PostTag>(
                j => j
                    .HasOne(pt => pt.Tag)
                    .WithMany(t => t.PostTags)
                    .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TagId),
                j => j
                    .HasOne(pt => pt.Post)
                    .WithMany(p => p.PostTags)
                    .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.PostId),
                j =>
                {
                    j.Property(pt => pt.PublicationDate).HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
                    j.HasKey(t => new { t.PostId, t.TagId });
                });
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string TagId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class PostTag
{
    public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }

    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

`PostTag` is a regular entity, and you can access it with `db.Set<PostTag>()` or from a Post or a Tag.  Note the (optional) navigation properties from `Post` and `Tag` to `PostTag`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I read the documentation but I don't understand how I can access PublicationDate from EF Core.

Comment: I was hoping to have more flexibility to directly have the property in the referenced entity (in the example the PublicationDate property in the Post entity).

Comment: No in the example the PublicationDate property in the PostTag (linking) entity.

Comment: Yes, I misspoke. I meant that taking your example as a reference I would have liked to have the PublicationDate property in the Post entity.

Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: Thanx, @DavidBrowne! I would never in a million years have figured this out, even with the doc link (which doesn't appear to contain the code you've extracted, BTW).